# JSON.stringify replacer - how to get full path

Tags: javascript, json

Replacer in below code write on console current processed field name

```js
let a = { a1: 1, a2:1 }
let b = { b1: 2, b2: [1,a] }
let c = { c1: 3, c2: b }


let s = JSON.stringify(c, function (field,value) {
  console.log(field); // full path... ???
  return value;
});
```

However I would like to get full "path" to field (not only its name) inside replacer function - something like this

```
c1
c2
c2.b1
c2.b2
c2.b2[0]
c2.b2[1]
c2.b2[1].a1
c2.b2[1].a2
```

How to do it?

Comment: _"As a function, it takes two parameters: the key and the value being stringified. The object in which the key was found is provided as the replacer's this parameter."_ - You will have to find yourself a way how to generate the path from the key and `this`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125398/how-to-enumerate-complex-javascript-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Decorator

`replacerWithPath` in snippet determine path using `this` (thanks @Andreas for this [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681176/json-stringify-replacer-how-to-get-full-path/61687616#comment109104564_61681176) ), `field` and `value` and some historical data stored during execution (and this solution support arrays)

```
JSON.stringify(c, replacerWithPath(function(field,value,path) {
  console.log(path,'=',value); 
  return value;
}));
```

```js
function replacerWithPath(replacer) {
  let m = new Map();

  return function(field, value) {
    let path= m.get(this) + (Array.isArray(this) ? `[${field}]` : '.' + field); 
    if (value===Object(value)) m.set(value, path);  
    return replacer.call(this, field, value, path.replace(/undefined\.\.?/,''))
  }
}


// Explanation fo replacerWithPath decorator:
// > 'this' inside 'return function' point to field parent object
//   (JSON.stringify execute replacer like that)
// > 'path' contains path to current field based on parent ('this') path
//   previously saved in Map
// > during path generation we check is parent ('this') array or object
//   and chose: "[field]" or ".field"
// > in Map we store current 'path' for given 'field' only if it 
//   is obj or arr in this way path to each parent is stored in Map. 
//   We don't need to store path to simple types (number, bool, str,...)
//   because they never will have children
// > value===Object(value) -> is true if value is object or array
//   (more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22482737/860099)
// > path for main object parent is set as 'undefined.' so we cut out that
//   prefix at the end ad call replacer with that path


// ----------------
// TEST
// ----------------

let a = { a1: 1, a2: 1 };
let b = { b1: 2, b2: [1, a] };
let c = { c1: 3, c2: b };

let s = JSON.stringify(c, replacerWithPath(function(field, value, path) {
  // "this" has same value as in replacer without decoration
  console.log(path);
  return value;
}));
```

**BONUS**: I use this approach to stringify objects with circular references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710921/860099)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the other answers I have this function which adds a third `path` argument to the call of `replacer`:

```js
function replacerWithPath(replacer) {
  const m = new Map();

  return function (field, value) {
    const pathname = m.get(this);
    let path;

    if (pathname) {
      const suffix = Array.isArray(this) ? `[${field}]` : `.${field}`;

      path = pathname + suffix;
    } else {
      path = field;
    }

    if (value === Object(value)) {
      m.set(value, path);
    }

    return replacer.call(this, field, value, path);
  }
}

// Usage

function replacer(name, data, path) {
  // ...
}

const dataStr = JSON.stringify(data, replacerWithPath(replacer));
```

**BONUS:**

I also created this function to iterate through an object in depth and to be able to use the replace function like with `JSON.stringify`.
The third argument to `true` will keep `undefined` values and empty objects.

It can be handy to modify and ignore values while iterating through an object, it returns the new object (without stringify).

```js
function walkWith(obj, fn, preserveUndefined) {
  const walk = objPart => {
    if (objPart === undefined) {
      return;
    }

    let result;

    // TODO other types than object
    for (const key in objPart) {
      const val = objPart[key];
      let modified;

      if (val === Object(val)) {
        modified = walk(fn.call(objPart, key, val));
      } else {
        modified = fn.call(objPart, key, val);
      }

      if (preserveUndefined || modified !== undefined) {
        if (result === undefined) {
          result = {};
        }

        result[key] = modified;
      }
    }

    return result;
  };

  return walk(fn.call({ '': obj }, '', obj));
}
```

**BONUS 2:**

I use it to transform a `data` object coming from a form submission and containing files / arrays of files in mixed multipart, files + JSON.

```js
function toMixedMultipart(data, bodyKey = 'data', form = new FormData()) {
  const replacer = (name, value, path) => {
    // Simple Blob
    if (value instanceof Blob) {
      form.append(path, value);

      return undefined;
    }

    // Array of Blobs
    if (Array.isArray(value) && value.every(v => (v instanceof Blob))) {
      value.forEach((v, i) => {
        form.append(`${path}[${i}]`, v);
      });

      return undefined;
    }

    return value;
  };

  const dataStr = JSON.stringify(data, replacerWithPath(replacer));
  const dataBlob = new Blob([dataStr], { type: 'application/json' });

  form.append(bodyKey, dataBlob);

  return form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom walk function inside your `replacer`. Here's an example using a generator walk function:

```js
const testObject = {a: 1, b: {a: 11, b: {a: 111, b: 222, c: 333}}, c: 3};

function* walk(object, path = []) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        yield path.concat(key);

        if (typeof value === 'object') yield* walk(value, path.concat(key));
    }
}

const keyGenerator = walk(testObject);

JSON.stringify(testObject, (key, value) => {
    const fullKey = key === '' ? [] : keyGenerator.next().value;

    // fullKey contains an array with entire key path
    console.log(fullKey, value);

    return value;
});
```

Console output:

```
  fullKey          |  value
-------------------|------------------------------------------------------------
  []               |  {"a":1,"b":{"a":11,"b":{"a":111,"b":222,"c":333}},"c":3}
  ["a"]            |  1
  ["b"]            |  {"a":11,"b":{"a":111,"b":222,"c":333}}
  ["b", "a"]       |  11
  ["b", "b"]       |  {"a":111,"b":222,"c":333}
  ["b", "b", "a"]  |  111
  ["b", "b", "b"]  |  222
  ["b", "b", "c"]  |  333
  ["c"]            |  3
```

This works, assuming the algorithm in `replacer` is depth-first and consistent across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There's just not enough information available in the replacer. These two objects have different shapes but produce the same sequence of calls:

```js
let c1 = { c1: 3, c2: 2 };
let c2 = { c1: { c2: 3 } };

const replacer = function (field, value) {
  console.log(field); // full path... ???
  return value;
};

JSON.stringify(c1, replacer);
// logs c1, c2
JSON.stringify(c2, replacer);
// logs c1, c2
```

You'll have to write something yourself.

Comment: Yeah, the good news is that the replacer goes through a predictable path, so you could write your recursive walker and collect the paths that way.

Comment: _"You'll have to write something yourself."_ - Is this really an "answer"?

Comment: Given that the question is specifically about the replacer function in `JSON.stringify`, I think a demonstration that what it's asking for isn't possible is helpful. A negative result is still a result!

Answer (score 0):

Something like that. You need to adjust it for arrays. I think that you can do it yourself. The idea is clear.

```js
let a = { a1: 1, a2:1 }
let b = { b1: 2, b2: [1,a] }
let c = { c1: 3, c2: b }

function iterate(obj, path = '') {
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
                iterate(obj[property], path + property + '.');
            }
            else {
                console.log(path + property);
            }
        }
    }
}

iterate(c)
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, however how to get paths inside `JSON.stringify` replacer function? (and for arrays your code produce `.1.` instead `[1]`) - some people say that this is impossible, others say that this is possible

Comment: In case that sequence is predictable, just keep the path in a variable in higher scope. And, I've mentioned that arrays should be adjusted. You as an experienced programmer can do it yourself.